# Integrating Excell file in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am developing a website in asp.net. In that project i want to add an excel sheet so that anyone using the site can use the excel file.

Comment: i am not getting the exact solution. It took lots of days. but still no result ... i hope my problem will sooner solved

Regards,

Comment: That's far away from an easy task...

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Thanks buds, Actually i want to use this excel instead SqlServer. like my project chooses an excel file and that file gets included in my project. Now my project can read data from that file like passwords, email addresses